# Fractal Transformers Optional Model Columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, transformer-model

I am using Fractal Transformers in Laravel 5. I have:

```
namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Models\Cake;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class CakeTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'user',
        'description'
    ];
    public function transform(Cake $cake)
    {
        $ar = [
            'name' => $cake->name,
            'url_name' => $cake->url_name,
            'user' => $cake->user->screenname,
            'date_created' => $cake->created_at
        ];

        return $ar;
    }

    public function includeUser(Cake $cake)
    {
        return $this->item($cake->user, new UserTransformer());
    }

    public function includeDescription(Cake $cake) {
        return $cake->description;
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work because `includeDescription` doesn't return the right kind of object, but from the above you can see what I'm trying to do.

For instance in my search I want to bring back much less data than if I were to load a whole page about the search item. E.g. for search I don't want to load the description, but for the page that contains details about the product I would want to.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For includes you have to return fractal resource. So you can use `return $this->item($cake, ['whatEverYouWantAsKey' => $cake->description]);`

Comment: Thanks, someone suggested a separate SearchTransformer, what are your thoughts on this?